# Как в Response передать JSON?

Tags: javascript

```
let response = new Response({ id: 1, name: 'name'}, { "status" : 200 , "statusText" : "OK" });
```

почему так не работает?

`UPDATE`

вот так возникает ошибка:

```
let response = new Response(
    { id: 1, name: 'name'},
    { "status" : 200 , "statusText" : "OK" }
);
response.json();
```

> TypeError: self.body.on is not a function

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что так не работает?

Comment: response.json() возвращает ошибку: `Error: TypeError: self.body.on is not a function`

Comment: где и как ты это все пробуешь?

Comment: в JEST. Требуется проверить обработку результата `fetch`. Для этого генерится Response.

Comment: в браузере работает, если сделать `JSON.stringify`

Comment: ага, сериализованный JSON работает, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Объект Response принимает в body данные для ответа, и параметры в виде объекта.

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("id",1);
data.append("name","Vasia");
let response = new Response(data,
    { id: 1, name: 'name',"status" : 200 , "statusText" : "OK"}        
);
response.json();
```

Как вариант можно так:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({id:1,name:"Vasia"});
```

Comment: так 2 и должны передаваться, разве нет?  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Response/Response#Example